# gdb gives error relating to iofwrite.c

Tags: c, gdb

I am using gdb to find out why I am getting a seg fault.  I run the command `gba myProg core` so I can see the core dump from the seg fault.  The core dump reads as follows.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  __GI__IO_fwrite (buf=0x7f32040167a0, size=1, count=2, fp=0x0) at iofwrite.c:37
37  iofwrite.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f3209bac700 (LWP 20157))]
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the error message.  It seems to be saying that the seg fault is due to iofwrite.c but I can't seem to find any information on such a file.  I assume it relates to fwrite.

Comment: We can't tell you the problem unless you post the code.

Comment: [iowrite.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/iofwrite.c) is part of glibc. Looks like you called smth like `fwrite(NULL, 100, 100, NULL)` and your prorgam segfaulted.

Comment: @Osiris, in this particular case, I think it is difficult to produce a MCVE, when all you have is a core dump, and the output of gdb.  Kamil Cuk, probably nailed the problem down, in his comment though.  Which should be enough to solve, or ask a new question.  I don't know, perhaps this question title should be something more like "How do I interpret the output of gdb"

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output you get when you give gdb the `bt` command after your program gets the SIGSEGV error? Then we can see where the error in your code caused the error in the libc code.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a NULL fp to fwrite().  It's impossible to answer more completely without code.

Answer (score 1):

I had encounted this question too, the reason was my output file name is invalid.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please add how output file is invalid. It has bad path of directory? It did not have access to write file to specific directory? The file which was created have different name? be more detailed about your solution.